# Software for tracking the changes you make to a file so that you can track your productivity

Tags: software-development, productivity

I'm looking for software for tracking the changes you make to a file so that you can track your productivity.

Does anything like this exist?

I'd like to measure my productivity over a time-window and look into the things that slowed me down and see how I could have improved.

Comment: It's possible on a technical level. E.g. [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) will record file changes. However, if you have a look at it, you'll notice that within a few seconds you can get 100.000 changed files, all changed not related to your productivity. Conclusion: this wil at least require you to do some configuration, e.g. which file types or changed by which software.

Comment: What kind of files you're thinking could be interesting to know.

Comment: I'm thinking about changes to my source files (`.js`, `.py`, ... etc) and I also want to integrate this with bash history so I can also measure how much time I'm wasting waiting for my slow code to run and when I need to go back and speed things up.